# Wrapper and custom object in list

Tags: wrapper-class, ui

How to show this elements in html.
I am new in salesforce and programming

```java
public with sharing class StockMarketSharesWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Wrapper> getAllCompanys(){
        // Define the list
        List<Wrapper> com = new List<Wrapper>(); 

        // Create account sObjects
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'U';
        w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
        Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'UAL';
        w.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
        Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
        w.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
        Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
        w.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;

        // Add accounts to the list
        com.add(w);
        com.add(w1);
        com.add(w2);
        com.add(w3);

        return com;
    }

    public class Wrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Ticker {get; set;}
    }
}
```

I want to show the list of "//Create account sObjects" in HTML with wrapper how should I do it?

---

**UPDATE**
I tried:

APEX

```
public with sharing class StockMarketSharesWrapper {   
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Wrapper> getAllCompanys(){
        // Define the list
        List<Wrapper> com = new List<Wrapper>(); 

        // Create account sObjects
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.Ticker = 'U';
        w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
        Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
        w1.Ticker = 'UAL';
        w1.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
        Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
        w2.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
        w2.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
        Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
        w3.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
        w3.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;

        // Add accounts to the list
        com.add(w);
        com.add(w1);
        com.add(w2);
        com.add(w3);

        return com;
    }

    public class Wrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Ticker {get; set;}
    } 
}
```

JS

```
import { wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllCompanys from '@salesforce/apex/StockMarketSharesWrapper.getAllCompanys';

export default class wrapperList extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getAllCompanys, {}) companys;
  columns = [{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' }, { label: 'Ticker', fieldName: 'Ticker' }]
}
```

JS v2

```
    Ticker= '';
    Name='';

    @wire(getAllCompanys, { })
    fetchCompanies(data, error){
        alert('is in ????');
        if (error){
            this.Ticker= JSON.stringify(error);
            this.Name= JSON.stringify(error);
            return;
        }
        if(data.data){
            this.Ticker =data.data.Ticker;
            this.Name =data.data.Name
        }
        
    }
```

HTML

```
<template>
    {Ticker}
    {Name}
    {Companys}
  </template>
```

nothing works ;/

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Among other issues with your code, which hopefully someone with more time at the moment can address, please note that  the code keeps overwriting the values of `w.Ticker` and `w.Name` - you do not use `w1`, `w2` or `w3` after you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/contactList) of this in the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/) repository published by salesforce.com.

Your JS should look like:

```
import { wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllCompanys from '@salesforce/apex/StockMarketSharesWrapper.getAllCompanys';

export default class MyLwcComponent extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getAllCompanys, {}) companys;
  columns = [{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' }, { label: 'Ticker', fieldName: 'Ticker' }]
}
```

And your HTML can look like:

```
<template>
  <lightning-datatable data={companys.data} columns={columns} key-field="Name">
  </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

See also the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/) documentation.

Edit: Your Apex is reusing the same variable, despite creating new wrappers; this is why most of your data would be blank.

```
    Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
    w.Ticker = 'U';
    w.Name = 'Unity Software Inc';
    Wrapper w1 = new Wrapper();
    w1.Ticker = 'UAL';
    w1.Name = 'United Airlines Holdings, Inc.' ;
    Wrapper w2 = new Wrapper();
    w2.Ticker ='DAOOU' ;
    w2.Name = 'Crypto 1 Acquisition Corp Unit';
    Wrapper w3 = new Wrapper();
    w3.Ticker = 'GLLIU';
    w3.Name ='Globalink Investment Inc. Unit' ;
```

Edit 2: There was a `.data` missing in the template. I build the entire thing in to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/7de4205525e15f1bcd7b3fabf32f1e60).

Comment: I tryed copy paste your code from js and html but that is not working. Do i have correct writed my apex class ?? What schould I do ?

Comment: @1skora As commented on earlier by Moonpie, you used `w` for all your assignments, instead of `w1`, `w2`, etc. I'd expect your current output to have several blank lines where data should be.

Comment: Then can u show me how that schould look like correctly ?

Comment: @1skora Sure, I edited that in.

Comment: Even now its not working, i am feeling so dumb ;/ sorry for wasting your time ;/

I tryed

 @wire(getAllCompanys, { Key: "sth"})
    fetchCompanies(data, error){
        alert('is in ????');
        if (error){
            this.Ticker= JSON.stringify(error);
            this.Name= JSON.stringify(error);
            return;
        }
        if(data.data){
            this.Ticker =data.data.Ticker;
            this.Name =data.data.Name
        }
        alert('jakie dane: ' + data);
    }

Comment: @1skora Fret not; we all started out at the beginning. Would you like to send me a copy of your code by email, I can review this offline, or you can edit your code into the question, I'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: I willl be realy glad I just past my code in answer

Comment: @1skora `wrapperList` is incorrect; the first letter of the class name must be uppercase: `WrapperList`. Aside from that, the first version should work. Give me a few minutes, I'm writing up a full example for you.

Comment: @1skora Was missing a few characters from the template. I made a gist for you, this should set you straight. Also, it should be noted that you had a number of technical problems in your code, which is why you were having a hard time of it. You were returning a list, but trying to use it as if it were a single variable. Your wire handler also read `(data, error)` instead of `({ data, error })`. Don't worry, you'll get it one day, it just takes some practice.

Comment: You are the GOD realy thank you for your help <3

Answer (score -2):

You have to stringify the data in Apex and return to js side and then store it to object and iterate that object in html

Comment: No, you don't have to stringify/serialize the data.